# Heroku running rails 2.x Puma error

Tags: heroku, puma

I'm getting the error below in my heroku logs.  The Puma line and config file are the defaults as supplied by Heroku.

Starting process with command bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb invalid option: -C

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a puma version issue.  I was running an older version that does not support the -C option.